# Is it possible to raise a window using a keyboard shortcut in Gnome3?

Tags: gnome, d-bus

I have recently shifted from KDE4 to Gnome3. In KDE you can create application specific keyboard shortcuts to raise windows. I typically create one each for firefox, thunderbird, my terminal etc. That way switching between windows is lightning quick. Gnome doesn't seem to have that kind of functionality. Also I do not like Gnome3's window switching scheme (alt-tab).

Hence I was wondering if its possible to raise windows through DBUS? If it is, then it will be possible to write a script and assign a keyboard shortcut to that.

Comment: If you want to raise and focus the window, `wmctrl` can do it.

Comment: How "intelligent" is the KDE shortcut method? eg. How does it handle multiple windows of the same application? There are several X tools which working singly or together can do what you want.. But which ones you use can depends on how sophisticated you want to make it.

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the clue, wmctrl did the trick
@fred the KDE shortcut method works only for single windows, but thats good enough for me, coz I only use single windows for firefox, thunderbird etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a script on fluxbox wiki that uses `wmctrl` to find an application and raise its window if it's already running.  Otherwise, the script launches the application.  I'm using that script with tweaks to support arguments, which I have [documented on my blog](http://www.humbug.in/2011/single-keyboard-shortcut-to-launchraise-an-application/).

1. Make sure `wmctrl` is installed.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. Add the following script to your path (possibly in `$HOME/bin/find_app.sh`), and make it executable.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Find_app

   # Author: Lucas van Staden (lvs at dedmeet.com / http://www.dedmeet.com)
   # This little script will try and find the application attempting to start
   # in the running processes, and if found, focus the application
   # if not found, a new instance will start

   # usage:
   # find_app.sh <application with full path>

   # params
   # 1 - application to start (full path)

   # helper applications
   DOLLARONE=$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/[\t ]*$//') #Delete trailing spaces
   WMCTRL=`which wmctrl`;
   GREP=`which grep`;
   APPLICATION=$(echo $DOLLARONE | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
   if [ "x$APPLICATION" != "x$DOLLARONE" ]; then
     APPARGS=$(echo $DOLLARONE | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
   fi
   BASENAME=`basename $APPLICATION`;
   BASENAME=`echo $BASENAME | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`
   FOUND=0;
   function findwindow {
   # 1 = BASENAME
   # 2 = WMCTRL
   # 3 = GREP
           IFS=$'\n';
           for RUNNING in `$2 -l -x`
           do
                   if [ `echo $RUNNING | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" | $3 -c $DOLLARONE` -gt 0 ]
                   then
                           HOSTNAME=`hostname`
                           WINDOW=${RUNNING#*${HOSTNAME} }
                           $2 -a $WINDOW
                           FOUND=1;
                   fi;
           done
   }
   if [ "x$APPARGS" = "x" ]; then
     findwindow $BASENAME $WMCTRL $GREP;
     if [ $FOUND -eq 0 ]
     then
             $APPLICATION &
             sleep 2;
             # Try and find the application, after opened
             findwindow $BASENAME $WMCTRL $GREP;
             if [ $FOUND -eq 0 ]
             then
                     # Still not found, wait a bit more, and try again
                     sleep 3;
                     findwindow $BASENAME $WMCTRL $GREP;
             fi
     fi
   else
     $APPLICATION $APPARGS &
   fi
   ```
3. Update the desktop entry files of the applications you want to have a singular shortcut for launching as well as raising, so that the applications are invoked through the above script.

   For example:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```

   Edit `firefox.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/` and change the `Exec` line to refer to `find_app.sh`:

   ```
   Exec=find_app.sh "firefox %u"
   ```
4. Now add a keyboard shortcut for your default browser:

   System Settings | Keyboard | Shortcuts | Launchers | Launch Web Browser
5. Restart gnome shell:  Press `Alt r` to bring up the run dialog.  Type `r` and press `Enter`.

You should now be able to launch/raise your browser using a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Gilles Its an open source script, not upto me to release it or not, i thought its just too long a solution to be posted here. Will update my answers with more details

Comment: there should be a gnome3 native way of implementing this using libbamf library I think.

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar tool called [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/#id270150). It seems to be very much the same as wmctrl. The main advantage over the latter perhaps, is that it uses X Window IDs rather than strings to handle windows. I don't know if it matters much in your case though.
But say you are using Chrome, opened on a website, the title of which has Mozilla, then you may not be able to identify the application from the window's title.